# ASP.NET Add-migration issue

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I moved from one PC to a new PC where I had to re-install every thing including `VS2017`. But when I run my same project from old PC to new PC (both Windows 10) app runs fine. I then added a new model and when I run the following Package Manager console command I get the following error.

```
PM> add-migration myMigration -context TestProjContext
```

**Error**:

> An error occurred while calling method 'ConfigureServices' on startup class 'Startup'. Consider using IDbContextFactory to override the initialization of the DbContext at design-time. Error: Could not find 'UserSecretsIdAttribute' on assembly 'ef, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>   No parameterless constructor was found on 'MyProjContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'MyProjContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'MyProjContext'.

**UPDATE**

1. This project was upgraded from VS2015 to VS2017 and hence the `project.json` was gone (replaced by `.csproj`. And if I recall correctly this is the first time since moving to VS2017 that I've run the `add-migration` command

**Startup.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using TestProj.Data;
using TestProj.Models;
using TestProj.Services;

namespace TestProj
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets();
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connection = @"Server=MyWin10Desktop;Database=MySQL2012Db;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            services.AddDbContext<TestProjContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseIdentity();
            app.UseSession(); //me: must come before app.UseMvc()

            // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

**TestProj.csproj file**: [Note: Since app was upgraded from `VS2015` to `VS2017` the upgrade wizard removed the `project.json` and added this `.csproj` file instead

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>ABCTest</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>ABCTest</PackageId>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-ABCTest-6af8ade3-87ff-4468-a9ce-8bb69c696ab8</UserSecretsId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.1</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\ABCTestP.pubxml" />
    <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml" />
    <None Remove="Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile1.pubxml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*;Views\**\*;Areas\**\Views">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="2.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.3.327" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="EPPlus.Core" Version="1.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

 <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: You may be hitting this https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/209

Comment: @Smit I think you've put me on the right track. I've just added `item 1` in my UPDATE section above. The error started after I moved my web project from `VS2015` to `VS2017`. Since I don't have `project.json` anymore, which section of the link - that you've provided - should I follow?

Comment: Which version of packages you are using? Share your csproj file.

Comment: @Smit I just added the file you requested in **UPDATE 2** of my post.

Comment: That csproj does not contain any references. Are you able to build successfully? Where are you referencing EF Core packages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151760/discussion-between-nam-and-smit).

Comment: @Smit Most of the packages have versions `1.1.1`. And yes, the project is built successfully and the app runs even better and faster than it was in VS2015. The only issue is I'm unable to run add-migration command

Comment: @Smit I had mistakenly copied the content of `TestProj.csproj.user` file in UPDATE 2 above. I have corrected it now by copying the content of `TestProj.csproj` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part is this:

> No parameterless constructor was found on `MyProjContext`. Either add a parameterless constructor to `MyProjContext` or add an implementation of `IDbContextFactory` in the same assembly as `MyProjContext`

The `IDbContextFactory` way is the prefered way of achieving this in Entity Framework Core, because you can use the same tooling as in `Startup.cs`.
From the [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext):

> You may also provide an implementation of `IDbContextFactory<TContext>`. EF tools can use this factory to create an instance of your DbContext. **This may be required in order to enable specific design-time experiences such as migrations**.
>   Implement this interface to enable design-time services for context types that do not have a public default constructor. Design-time services will automatically discover implementations of this interface that are in the same assembly as the derived context.

For example:

```cs
public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyProjContext>
{
    public MyProjContext Create()
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Hosting:Environment");
        return Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), environmentName);
    }

    public MyProjContext Create(DbContextFactoryOptions options)
    {
        return Create(
            options.ContentRootPath,
            options.EnvironmentName);
    }

    public MyProjContext Create(string basePath, string environmentName)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var Configuration = builder.Build();

        var connectionName = nameof(MyProjContext);
        var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionName);
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString) == true)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not find a connection string named '{connectionName}'.");

        // init SQL server
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyProjContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new MyProjContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I've just added my `Startup.cs` file to my original post above so you or someone can help me on what exactly I need to do in the Startup.cs file. From what I am gathering from reading other online articles that somehow I need to create your `DbContextFactory` class. Is this going to be a standalone class under the Model folder? Also, did you mean your class name to be  `TestProjContextFactory ` instead of `DbContextFactory` as in this [MSDN example](https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/staging/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html#use-idbcontextfactory)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but getting the error that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45654180/1232087). What I may be missing?